# homebrew. Cant start service. get "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error - Postgres - Mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

I am trying to re-install Postgres via home-brew on Mac.
I uninstalled Postgres, updated home-brew and ran the install command for `brew install postgres`

when I run `brew services start postgresql`

I get the below error message:

Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/edac/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` exited with 5.

When I try to start a server through the Postgres app I receive this message:

```
Required PostgreSQL version not installed

The data directory was initialized with PostgreSQL 13.

This copy of Postgres.app includes the following PostgreSQL versions: 14.

Please try downloading a different release of Postgres.app.
```

originally when I installed Postgres all I did was run the home-brew cli and install the app and I was good to go. Not sure what's gone wrong.

Comment: You already have databases on your system. If you still need them, have a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The issue is the previous install of postgres was postgres 13, and it created a database under:

```
/usr/local/var/postgres
```

which is now incompatible with the version of postgres you're installing, which is version 14.

First question: Do you care about your data?

> If not then you can simply delete that folder and attempt to restart the service.

to delete and restart the service do:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
initdb --locale=C -E UTF8 /usr/local/var/postgres
brew services start postgresql
```

Otherwise you need to install postgresql@13, and perform a database migration, which can be summed up as follows:

install older postgres, make sure it's stopped

```
brew install postgresql@13
brew services stop postgresql@13
brew services stop postgres
```

delete the postgres 13 database created by the installation of postgresql@13

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgresql@13
```

move old data to compatible driver folder:

```
mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgresql@13
```

Now we do the upgrade. First cd to the database folder

```
cd /usr/local/var
```

Construct a new blank database, with locale C, encoding of UTF8

```
initdb --locale=C -E UTF8 -D postgres
```

Perform the upgrade itself:

```
pg_upgrade -d postgresql@13 -D postgres -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@13/13.4/bin -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.0/bin -v
```

This should end in success. If it doesn't (e.g. locale/encoding is wrong), then chose the locale and encoding that matches the database.

Finally restart the postgres service:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

Comment: For newer versions of homebrew, you will need to look at `/opt/homebrew/var/postgres` rather than `/usr/local/var/postgres`

Comment: That's on silicon macs, where it has been decided to install native binaries in `/opt/homebrew`, but to still leave non-native binaries (running under rosetta2) in `/usr/local`

Answer (score 16):

The problem is really what @Petesh said. But, the resolution for me was simpler.

When you upgrade your postgresql with brew, it logs a success message. One thing registered will be:

```
To migrate existing data from a previous major version of PostgreSQL run:
  brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

So the only thing you need to do is to run the command below:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

And of course you need to restart the service:

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

If you want to make sure it worked, you can run the start command too:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

Comment: cool - I didn't realize that there was a brew helper for this

Comment: I had to run the command twice but this is the one which fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

I faced a similar problem with postgresql 11 and restarting the service did not help. The issue arose when my MacBook restarted abruptly.

After checking the ports and trying out all the possible solutions, I decided to look into the logs.

```
tail -n 100 /usr/local/var/log/postgresql@11.log
```

This gave me the last 100 lines of the log where I found this:

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 479) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgresql@11"?
```

Clearly, the issue was with postmaster.pid so I deleted it:

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgresql@11/postmaster.pid
```

Started the postgres service again:

```
brew services start postgresql@11
```

and voila! It worked.

Comment: This also worked for me. Had the same problem, postgres wasn't working after my MacBook shut down abruptly. 
My pid file location was `/opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `postgresql` is already started before running the start command.

So do restart it instead of starting, by the following command:

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this for Apache. To fix it, I unloaded the plist file. In your case

```
launchctl unload /Users/edac/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
launchctl load /Users/edac/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Then I re-ran the start services command and it worked.

```
brew services start postgresql
```

Comment: This worked for me. The problem I was having was that it kept wanting to run as the root user. /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log said "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server. Doing these steps let "brew services start postgresql" work by running as me instead of root for some reason.

Answer (score -2):

Happened suddenly but following step fixed the restart issue:

rm /usr/local/var/postgresql@11/postmaster.pid worked for me because instance was already running.

```
brew services start postgresql@14
```

Comment: This seems to be the same as [this previous answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436715/100490)